# Graphic Magic with Aspect Ratio

Tags: node.js

I am working on graphic magic in node.js

here is my code

```
gm('images/imagename').resize(200, 109, '^>').write('images/newimagename', function (err) {

});
```

Which is working fine. But problem is that, it is not mainlining the aspect ratio

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be working for me with GraphicsMagick 1.3.19 2013-12-31 Q8 on OSX and "GraphicsMagick and ImageMagick for node.js version 1.17.0".  Can you post your versions of GM and node.js package version as well as the original image size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
gm('images/imagename').resize(200, 109, '^').write('images/newimagename', function (err) {

});
```

^ take care for aspect ratio